# jQuery- Changing Opacity with mouseenter and leave. Image still appears once hide button is clicked

Tags: jquery, image, opacity, mouseenter, mouseleave

I'm doing an assignment for school where we are trying to learn the basics of jQuery.
One of the requirements is that when a user hovers over the "Hide" button the image's opacity changes, and when the mouse leaves the "Hide" button the opacity returns to normal. Clicking hide, of course, makes the image disappear and "Show" should make it reappear.

The problem I'm having is that even after the user clicks "Hide" the image will fade back in after the mouse has moved from that button. I'm using a boolean called isHidden, which starts as being declared false and gets changed to true when "Hide" is and clicked and back to false when "Show" is clicked. I also have some console logs to make sure the isHidden variable is getting the values I'm expecting.

I've looked at other posts here trying to find similar problems. I know there has to be an error in my logic or maybe I'm just misunderstanding how these functions mouseenter and mouseleave work.

I'm really just looking for someone to maybe explain what I'm doing wrong here and some better ways to go about solving this problem. I've tried using .hover() and moving around the if statement that checks what isHidden is, but I'm getting the same results. Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Image variable for easy use
  var image = $("img");
  var isHidden = false;

  //Hide effect
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    isHidden = true;
    image.hide();
  }); //End hidebutton

  //Show effect
  $("#show").click(function() {
    isHidden = false;
    image.show();
  });

  //Hover effect
  if (isHidden == false) {
    $("#hide").mouseenter(function() {
      image.fadeTo(1000, 0.4);
      console.log("mouseenter isHidden is  " + isHidden);
    });
    $("#hide").mouseleave(function() {
      image.fadeTo(1000, 1);
      console.log("mouseleave isHidden is  " + isHidden);
    });
  }

  //Move effect
  $("#move").click(function() {
    image.animate({
      left: '400px'
    }, "slow");
  }); //End of movebutton

  //Enlarge effect
  $("#enlarge").click(function() {
    image.animate({
      height: '400px',
      width: '400px'
    }); //End of animate
  }); //End of enlargebutton

  $("#circle").click(function() {

  }); //End of circlebutton
}); //End of $document
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>jQuery simple assignment. Demonstrate that you can use basic jQuery functions.</p>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/18/10/56/smiley-163510_960_720.jpg" border=0 style="height:200px;width:200px;position:absolute;left: 100px;top: 150px;">
<p></p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<p></p>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<button id="enlarge">Enlarge</button>
<button id="circle">Circle</button>
```

Comment: The problem I see is that you have a conditional statement that then includes the event, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, controls. So when the page loads, this condition is only executed the once instead of each time the event occurs. You will want to use your condition inside the event function.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon my comment.

With your current code, you execute the `if` statement on `ready`. This means that the callbacks for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are bound only under that one condition. This works the first time, but as soon as the image is hidden, the condition is changed but the callbacks are still bound to the events.

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  //Image variable for easy use
  var image = $("img");
  var isHidden = false;

  //Hide effect
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    isHidden = true;
    image.hide();
  }); //End hidebutton

  //Show effect
  $("#show").click(function() {
    isHidden = false;
    if (parseFloat(image.css("opacity")) < 1) {
      image.fadeTo(100, 1);
    } else {
      image.show();
    }
  });

  //Hover effect
  $("#hide").mouseenter(function() {
    if (isHidden == false) {
      image.fadeTo(1000, 0.4);
      console.log("mouseenter isHidden is  " + isHidden);
    }
  });
  $("#hide").mouseleave(function() {
    if (isHidden == false) {
      image.fadeTo(1000, 1);
      console.log("mouseleave isHidden is  " + isHidden);
    }
  });

  //Move effect
  $("#move").click(function() {
    image.animate({
      left: '400px'
    }, "slow");
  }); //End of movebutton

  //Enlarge effect
  $("#enlarge").click(function() {
    image.animate({
      height: '400px',
      width: '400px'
    }); //End of animate
  }); //End of enlargebutton

  $("#circle").click(function() {

  }); //End of circlebutton
}); //End of $document
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>jQuery simple assignment. Demonstrate that you can use basic jQuery functions.</p>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/18/10/56/smiley-163510_960_720.jpg" border=0 style="height:200px;width:200px;position:absolute;left: 100px;top: 150px;">
<p></p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<p></p>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<button id="enlarge">Enlarge</button>
<button id="circle">Circle</button>
```

Also look at the `show` button. If the hide button is clicked, then the opacity is adjusted. When you then click show, it is unhidden, yet still in the partially hidden state. So we update that.

You may also want to look at `.hover()`. is basically the same as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` except it's all in one. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, helped a bunch! I was able to get the hover() to work as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the your conditional statement

`if (isHidden === false)`

inside your mouseenter and mouseleave event.

And in your  $("#show").click function use this:

`image.fadeTo("fast",1)` instead of `image.show()`

so the image would always be in opacity 1 everytime you click the show button :)